# Which language of Scrabble scores the most points on average per game?

Tags: scrabble

Some languages have more words than others, especially 2-3 letter words, which would probably allow for a higher average game score.

For example, although the same language, English, the Collins 2019 UK dictionary, compared to the NASPA 2018 US dictionary has much more words in general, especially game-changer 2 and 3-letter words like "ze", "zo", "ja", "qin", and "zea". https://scrabbleplayers.org/w/How_Collins_differs

In fact, top players/computers will score an average of 450 playing CSW (Collins UK) versus playing 425 NSW/TWL (NASPA US).

I'd like to know what language allows for most scoring potential. I would assume the language with the largest dictionary, heavily biased toward 2-3 letter words for hooks and parallel plays, would score the most. I'm not sure what language that would be.

Comment: Not an answer, but here's a list of championships in non-English that might be useful. F=French, S=Spanish, D=Duplicate, W=also world championship: 
Argentina S, Belgium FD/Dutch, Benin FD, Cameroon FD, Chile S, Colombia S, Congo FD, Costa Rica S, Czech Republic Czech, DRC FD, France FDW, Greece Greek, Italy Italian, Ivory Coast FD, Lebanon FD, Madagascar FD, Mexico S, Moroccan FD, Netherlands mostly Dutch D, Panama S, Poland Polish, Quebec FD, River Plate S, Romania Romanian/F, Senegal FD, Slovakia Slovak, Spain SW, Sweden Swedish, Switzerland FD, Togo FD, Tunisia FD, Uruguay S, Venezuela S

Comment: I can assure that it's ***not*** Dutch: Twenty "E"'s, twelve "A"'s, and two each of "J" and "Z" worth only 5.